# Tapered edges in cytoscape.js

Tags: graph, cytoscape.js

Is there a way to implement tapered edges in cytoscape.js (see Danny Holten, Petra Isenberg, Jean-Daniel Fekete, and J. Van Wijk (2010) Performance Evaluation of Tapered, Curved, and Animated Directed-Edge Representations in Node-Link Graphs. Research Report, Sep 2010.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the [edge style documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-line) and this [demo](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/edge-types/), there currently is no tapered style available. Also, the edge lines width propery is most likely not capable of recieving multiple width inputs for one edge.

If you really need this (very advanced) feature, you can always go to the [cytoscape.js GitHub](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js) and create an issue request for this.

**EDIT:**

A tapered edge has one slim and one thicc end like this, right? :D
[image]

Comment: Yes, that's correct Stephan T., they look like that. Thanks for the response.